# How can I format this string in jquery so that it will include the value of the title variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, format

I need to find a way to format the string such that I can replace "_TITLE_TO_REPLACE_" with the title. I have tried using single quotes so that the title can be entered in that spot, but I don't know how to escape the quotes around FavoriteWallpaper and Wallpaper, such that the URL.Action call is valid.

```
var title = $(this).parent().siblings(".imageLink").children().attr('title');

$(this).attr('href', function() {
        var url = '<%: Url.Action("FavoriteWallpaper", "Wallpaper", new { wallpaperId= "_TITLE_TO_REPLACE_"}) %>';
        return url;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming you need to do this after the page renders your url.action.

> return
>   url.replace('_TITLE_TO_REPLACE_',title);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = '<%: Url.Action("FavoriteWallpaper", "Wallpaper", new { wallpaperId= "' + title + '"}) %>';
```

Comment: That generated this in HTML.

wallpaperId=&#39;%20%2B%20title%20%2B%20&#39;